# Skip BeforeAll, Before, After Steps in Cucumber Conditionally

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have a Cucumber feature that uses @BeforeAll, @Before, and @After Steps to connect and post data to a URL client. This is not necessary for the tests to actually run, just some book keeping on our end.

Right now I have some try-catch blocks to make sure the client is running(it has a tendency to shutdown when we don't want it) and if an exception is thrown it just marks the Steps as PASSED and moves on to actually running the Scenarios.

I would like to have the Step Status set to Skip instead of Passed and log a message so we can make note of the client being down again without failing the entire test suite, which is what it was doing before I added the try-catch to ignore the client failure.

Anyway is this a really wordy way to ask.
How do I skip an @BeforeAll, @Before, and @After step based on a condition?

StepDefs.java

```java
boolean isConnected = true;

@BeforeAll()
public static void connectToClient(){
    try{
        client.Connect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        isConnected = false;
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        //Skip @BeforeAll Step
}

@Before(order = 0)
public static void getBeforeData(Scenario scenario){
    if(isConnected){ client.sendData(scenario); }
    else { //Skip @Before Step }
}

@After(order = 0)
public static void legAfterData(Scenario scenario){
    if(isConnected){ client.sendData(scenario) };
    else { //Skip @After Step }

}
```

Comment: Short answer: This isn't possible.

Comment: Darn, I was worried that would be the case

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario where I intercept the Before and After calls to setup pre-requisites or to clean up the test environment.
E.g.

1. If the cucumber scenario has @needsOktaUser tag, then before the test executes, the 'before hook' creates an Okta user.
2. If the cucumber scenario has @deleteTenant tag, then after the test executes, the 'after hook' deletes the newly created tenant.

I hope this helps!

```
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

@Before("@needsOktaUser")
    public void createUser() {
        log.info("Creating user");
        oktaAPISteps.createOktaUser(driver);
    }

 @After("@deleteTenant")
    public void deleteTenant() {
        HaasAPICalls haasAPICalls = new HaasAPICalls();
        haasAPICalls.deleteTenant("CreatedTenantId");
    }
```